# Can't find my device with adb

Tags: android, debugging, adb, samsung-mobile

I'm running adb on ubuntu, and my app (that I'd like to test) on a Galaxy S3. Got my S3 in debugging mode, I've edited /lib/udev/rules.d/51.android and .android files, restarted adb, and my laptop, but no luck. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Is your laptop having device driver for particular device?

Comment: I'm on linux. `lsusb` returns Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04e7:6680 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]

Answer (score -1):

Try this on command prompt:

```
sudo -s
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Some more things you can try as I often find this helpful.

Check the Data Card, it might have problem.
Plug the data card to another port on the system.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't help.